# Android: loading of JPEG or any other file to VideoView from assets

Tags: android, jpeg, android-videoview

I properly display `VideoView` on my `Activity`.
I want to load jpeg file to this `VideoView` (it has to be `VideoView`).
My file to is in directory (and it has to be there):

```
/assets/data/multimedia/no_picture.jpg
```

My VideoView is:

```
multimediaContainer = ((MultimediaContainer) findViewById(R.id.questionMultimedia));
```

Now i try to use just this code:

```
private void setMultimedia(String path)
{
   String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/assets/multimedia/no_picture.jpg";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    multimediaContainer.setVideoURI(uri);
    multimediaContainer.start();
}
```

I tried used getAssets() or tried to pass to setVideoPath parsed Uri but it does not work (or i did it wrong).
 I always recieve "this video can not be displayed"
I know there are many answers "use raw directory". And this isn't suitable idea for me.
Can anybody assist me with this?

Comment: possibly because it is not a video ?

Comment: Doc describes VideoView as able to show jpeg.

Comment: Oh my... my mistake. I go there: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html and i wrongly assumed that this is description of VideoView. This is as i see general descripton. Anyway is there any component which can show image and movie?

Comment: i'm afraid you'll have to handle 2 components

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to show something like a preview image for your video right?
You can just build a RelativeLayout where an ImageButton stay on top of your VideoView, so you can set your Image to your ImageButton and implement the onClick to hide the ImageButton and start your video...

Is my interpretation of your problem right?

Comment: My intention is to show in the same place image or video (depends on situation). I know there is ImageView but i want to avoid if it is possible situation of handling these two components.

Comment: I think the best approach is to handle the content yourself just using  View.GONE to the appropriate view